# get all td names associated with checked checkboxes and show in html input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i am developing a quote generator. what i am trying to do is when the user select a feature it should display associated tfeature name in html input field with id features

here is what i have tried

html

```
 <table class="table" id="table">
                                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col"></th>
                                            <th scope="col">Features</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Description</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>

                                                <div class="form-check">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" name="product" value="300" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1"></label>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>Homepage</td>
                                            <td>Simplistic design with standard element</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" name="product" value="200" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1"></label>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>Login</td>
                                            <td>Standard Login with forgot password functionality</td>
                                        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
                <div class="form-group">
input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Feature 1, Feature 2, ..." value="" id="features">
                                </div>
  <input type="button" value="Get Selected" class="tble_submit" onclick="GetSelected()" />
```

so here when user select a checkbox the feature field like homepage, login should be displayed in html input field

here is updated jquery code

```
       <script src="../js/checkbox-total.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".tble_submit").click(function() {
            $('.table tr input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                var abc = [];
                var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
                //used :not(:first-child) to skip first element (the checkbox td)
                $('td:not(:first-child)', $row).each(function(i) {
                    abc.push($row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text());

                })



                $.each(abc, function(i, v) {
                    document.getElementById("features").value += v
                })


            });
        });

    </script>
```

but it is not working.

here when i select 2 features it should display homepage,login in input field but it shows description of login in input field

[image]

output - homepage,homepage,login,login

expected output - Homepage, Login

Comment: try to use `td:nth-child(2)` instead to select the second td element

Comment: yes did that also but it shows only last selected ... if i do as u said it shows login only and not homepage

Comment: you should do concatenation when updating the input `document.getElementById("features").value += v`

Comment: FYI: the `not(:first-child)` will select all the td except the first one

Comment: i did changes as u said [ abc.push($row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text());]  by concatenating  output i recieved is - homepage,homepage,login,login

Comment: not(:first-child) is used to ignore the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(".tble_submit, input[name ='product']").click(function() {
   var abc = []; //move the array to here
   $('.table tr input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
     var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
     //used :not(:first-child) to skip first element (the checkbox td)
     $('td:nth-child(2)', $row).each(function(i) {
       abc.push($(this).text());
     });

   });

   document.getElementById("features").value = abc.join(',');
 });
```

Comment: i need to ask one more question is it possible to show associated features in input field on checkbox click

Comment: add `input[name ='product']` to the selector